# Could not load mysql2_adapter

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, mysql2

I am trying to use mysql2 to run tests. I am working on rspec. Running "rspec spec" comand on terminal, getting following error.

```
Coverage report generated for RSpec to /home/parthiv/projects/Groupize/SourceCode/white_label/coverage. 0.0 / 0.0 LOC (100.0%) covered.
/home/parthiv/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@white_label/gems/activesupport-4.1.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:247:in `require': Could not load 'active_record/connection_adapters/mysql2_adapter'. Make sure that the adapter in config/database.yml is valid. If you use an adapter other than 'mysql', 'mysql2', 'postgresql' or 'sqlite3' add the necessary adapter gem to the Gemfile. (LoadError)
    from /home/parthiv/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@white_label/gems/activesupport-4.1.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:247:in `block in require'
```

Ruby version - ruby 2.1.2p95

Mysql version - 5.6.20-1+deb.sury.org~precise+1 (Ubuntu)

Gemfile

```
gem 'mysql2'
```

config/database.yml

```
development: &default
  adapter: mysql2
  database: my_database_name
  encoding: utf8
  min_messages: warning
  pool: 5
  timeout: 5000
  user_name: root
  password: root
  socket: /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock

test:
  <<: *default
  database: white_label_test

staging:
  <<: *default
  adapter: postgresql
  database: white_label_staging

production:
  adapter: mysql2
  encoding: utf8
  database: <%= ENV['RDS_DB_NAME'] %>
  username: <%= ENV['RDS_USERNAME'] %>
  password: <%= ENV['RDS_PASSWORD'] %>
  host: <%= ENV['RDS_HOSTNAME'] %>
  port: <%= ENV['RDS_PORT'] %>
```

Appropriate you help.

Comment: 1. do you have `mysql2` gem installed? (I know silly question :) ) 2. does your app work? can you load rails console and create any record in DB

Comment: @gotva - yes mysql12 installed but app not working

Comment: there are a lot of places where it can be broken. I suggest: check current default RAILS_ENV (`echo $RAILS_ENV` - it should be blank), check that gem `mysql2` belongs to all or at least development group in Gemfile, check that `bundle show mysql2` returns the path to gem, approve that you run console as `bundle exec rails c`

Comment: what version of mysql2 gem got installed? check your gemfile.lock.

Comment: I have installed mysql2 (0.3.16). It's working after reinstall mysql2 gem. Thanks.